# Why is my loop not following its condition?

Tags: python

so im working on this code for school and i dont know much about python. Can someone tell me why my loop keeps outputting invalid score when the input is part of the valid scores. So if i enter 1, it will say invalid score but it should be valid because i set the variable valid_scores= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].
This code has to allow the user to enter 5 inputs for six different groups and then add to a list which will find the sum of the list and the avarage of the list.

Code:

```
valid_scores =[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for group in groups: 
    scores_for_group = []
    valid_scores_loops=0
    print("What do you score for group {group_name} as a player?"\
         .format(group_name=group))
    while valid_scores_loops < 5:
        valid_scores=True
        player_input =input("* ")
        if player_input==valid_scores:
            player1.append(player_input)
            scores_for_player.append(int(player_input))
        else:
            if player_input!=valid_scores:
                valid_scores= False
                print("Invalid score!")
```

Comment: `player_input =input("* ")` returns a string. `1` is not equal to `"1"`. Cast the input to `int`

Comment: `player_input==valid_scores`,  you are comparing string with boolean?

Comment: What is the point of `valid_scores =[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` if you are just going ot set it to true

Comment: Instead of converting input to int I'd recommend to set the valid scores like this: `valid_scores = [str(i) for i in range(11)]`

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `valid_scores=True`, which overwrites your list of valid scores with a boolean value of `True`. Then, when you check `player_input!=valid_scores`, it will always return False.

What you want to do is get rid of the `valid_scores=True` line, cast the `player_input` to an integer using `int(player_input)`, then check `int(player_input) in valid_scores`. This will return True if the player inputs a string that can be cast to one of the integers in `valid_scores`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code there you are comparing a list (the valid values) with a string (the input.) This means you would have to give in a list for the statement to be correct. The right way is `input in valid_inputs`, which will check if any of the elements in the `valid_inputs` list equals the variable `input`. You're also assigning `True` to valid_inputs, which essentially deletes the list. Another error is that the `player1` and `scores_for_player` variables aren't defined in your code. To fix your code, you'll have to cast the input to an integer, the variable storing if the input is valid must be renamed, the variables `player1` and `scores_for_player` must be declared, and you probably should adjust your code with the fixes below.

You can also improve your code by replacing `while valid_score_loops < 5` with `for valid_score_loops in range(5)` because you don't change valid_score_loops in loop. Another way for you to express `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` is to convert it to a tuple: `(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)` or express it as a range: `range(0, 11)`.

Ranges are objects like lists and tuples that contain a sequence of numbers. The signatures of the `range` method are:

- `range(end)` with `start` equivalent to 0 and `step` to 1
- `range(start, end)` with `step` equivalent to 1
- `range(start, end, step)`

It will start at `start` and increase by `step` each time, ending before `end`.
Example:

```
>>> list(range(10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> list(range(3, 5))
[3, 4]
>>> list(range(1, 6, 2))
[1, 3, 5]
```

There is another optimization to make to your code. If the input isn't valid, it is invalid, so you don't have to check that in your code. To fix that, you can just remove the check if the argument isn't in the `valid_scores` list inside the `else` clause.

Comment: But it still wouldn't work. Their list is of ints, the input is a string.

Comment: @roganjosh I fixed everything I forgot to add the last time. EDIT: I think.